# countdown timer with progressbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using **final countdown** plug in. The problem is that when I reload the browser the second value start is  same time as before. Example : time has left 12 minutes 10 seconds . After 10 minutes later when I refresh the browser the minutes remains same. How can I change it?

Here is my work link 
http://rrfpractice.com/662121/mou/final-countdown/

**My script is:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // this code is for countdown
    $('.countdown').final_countdown({
    start: '0',
    end: ((((31+29+31+30+31+30+31+31+30+31+30+31)*24)*60)*60),
    now: ((((31+29+31+30+31+30+31+2)*24)*60)*60),
    seconds: {
        borderColor: '#2ecc71',
        borderWidth: '6'
    },
    minutes: {
        borderColor: '#2ecc71',
        borderWidth: '6'
    },
    hours: {
        borderColor: '#2ecc71',
        borderWidth: '6'
    },
    days: {
        borderColor: '#2ecc71',
        borderWidth: '6'
    }}, function() {
    // Finish callback
});
```

Comment: ok... why do you make so weird calculations? Take the timestamp like this: `new Date().getTime()` and your done.

Comment: Use local storage, cookie or session variable to store the lapsed time!

Comment: Thanks ..
please show me the code details ..

Comment: @pugazh please help me out . and give me the code details.

Comment: Can you post the link to final countdown plugin ? Not your example!

Comment: @pugazh here is the link 

http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Modern-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-Final-Countdown.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have a fixed time in the future and want a countdown.

Why not doing it like this: https://jsfiddle.net/mL1jfsLs/

**JS**

```
var start = new Date();  // now
var end = new Date("12/15/2016");

// get total seconds between the times
var delta = Math.abs(end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 1000;

// calculate (and subtract) whole days
var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
delta -= days * 86400;

// calculate (and subtract) whole hours
var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
delta -= hours * 3600;

// calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
delta -= minutes * 60;

// what's left is seconds
var seconds = Math.floor(delta) % 60;  // in theory the modulus is not required

alert("remaining: " + days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");
```

---

I don't know which library you are using, as you did not state that. But in your code there is a parameter `now` with a fixed value of yours. So you need to make this a variable value.
Therefor you can use the `new Date()` object to get the current timestamp and call `.getTime()` as shown in my example.
Maybe something like:
  `now: Math.floor( (new Date()).getTime() / 1000 )`